# How to get the registered accounts details of the phone in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I just need to get the account details of phone (if one or more) in both android and ios, how can i do this in react native?.

i have tried 'react-native-account-manager' package and get the email address in android using   AccountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google") method.

Comment: What accounts? If you mean email accounts or AppleID then on iOS you can't get any information like that.  It would be a privacy violation.

Comment: Yes i need to get the email and apple ID than we have entered when setup the phone.now issue with android, you meant we can get the apple id ?

Comment: I don’t know about android but you can’t get it on iOS. It would be a privacy violation. You can ask the user for their email...